# Use find() and with() together in Laravel query

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I have 2 tables `employees` and `employee_locations`. One employee has many locations. I need to find out one employee record with related latest `employee_locations` record. I wrote below query.

```
$employees = Employee::find([1])->with('employees.employee_locations')->latest()->first();
```

I am getting below error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the find method retrieves a collection of Eloquent objects, on which the with method can not be used. You must first specify your relations for the `Employee` objects and then use find.

The below code will retrieve the employee with the ids specified in `find` method and locations for each employee:

```php
$employees = Employee::with('employees.employee_locations')->find([1])
```

Comment: I am getting `Call to undefined relationship [employees] on model [App\Employee]. ` error.

Comment: It means your relationship is not defined properly in the Employee model. Can you show us your Employee model?

Comment: Thanks @arm. Here is Employee model `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Employee_location;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'emi_number', 'account_id'];

    public function employee_locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee_location::class);
    }
}`

Comment: since your relationship method is called employee_locations you should use that inside the with function like this: with('employee_locations')

Answer (score 1):

create a relation in your model. Something like this:

```
class Employee extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'employees';

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmployeeLocation::class, 'employeed_id');
    }
}

class EmployeeLocation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employee_locations';
}

$employees = Employee::with('location')->first();
or you do
$employees = Employee::with('location')->find(<employeed_id>);
```

Comment: I am getting `Call to undefined relationship [employees] on model [App\Employee]. ` error.

Comment: 2 things:
did you define an `employees` relation? Can you share what's inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This method

```
$employees = Employee::with('employees')->where('employeesid',$employeesid)- 
>get()->find($employeesid);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bloody. I am getting `Call to undefined relationship [employees] on model [App\Employee]. ` error.